# How to get posts that not older that 4 hours in linkedin company page using api?

Tags: postman, linkedin-api

I am currently using posts with an endpoint https://api.linkedin.com/rest/posts?q=author&author=urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3AXXXXXXXXX and it gives me all the posts from that author. But my need is I want only that posts that are not more than 4 hours old. I have tried to add **publishedAt** in params like image below
[image]
but it gives me **Invalid param. Please see errorDetails for more information.** error. How can I get that?